# shell script that displays the processes launched in the background

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a little problem here. I am trying to write a script shell that shows background processes, but at a certain date. The date is a positional parameter. I've searched on Internet about the date validation, but all the info I found got me confused. I'm fairly new at this so a little help would be appreciated.

How do I verify if the date parameter is in a valid format in my shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex :

```
#! /bin/bash

isDateInvalid()
{
    DATE="${1}"

    # Autorized separator char ['space', '/', '.', '_', '-']
    SEPAR="([ \/._-])?"

    # Date format day[01..31], month[01,03,05,07,08,10,12], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_1="((([123][0]|[012][1-9])|3[1])${SEPAR}(0[13578]|1[02])${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[01..30], month[04,06,09,11], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_2="(([123][0]|[012][1-9])${SEPAR}(0[469]|11)${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[01..28], month[02], year[1900..2099]
    DATE_3="(([12][0]|[01][1-9]|2[1-8])${SEPAR}02${SEPAR}(19|20)[0-9][0-9])"

    # Date format day[29], month[02], year[1904..2096]
    DATE_4="(29${SEPAR}02${SEPAR}(19|20(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])))"

    # Match the date in the Regex

    if ! [[ "${DATE}" =~ "^(${DATE_1}|${DATE_2}|${DATE_3}|${DATE_4})$" ]]
    then
        echo -e "ERROR - '${DATE}' invalid!"
    else
        echo "${DATE} is valid"
    fi
}

echo
echo "Exp 1: "`isDateInvalid '12/13/3550'`
echo "Exp 2: "`isDateInvalid '12/11/20322'`
echo "Exp 3: "`isDateInvalid '12 01 2000'`
echo "Exp 4: "`isDateInvalid '28-02-2014'`
echo "Exp 5: "`isDateInvalid '12_02_2002'` 
echo "Exp 6: "`isDateInvalid '12.10.2099'`
echo "Exp 7: "`isDateInvalid '31/11/2020'`
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question! But I'm at a begginer level now and all that seems too complicated for me to use. We did simple things in class and I thought this problem will be solved in the same manner. I'm confused myself about what I should do, but I can't explain any better than this, so here is the task: a shell script that displays the processes launched in the background at a certain date. The date is a positional parameter. Thanks again!

Comment: then you have to accept the answer, and post the issue with a new question

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to input a date and filter background processes by that input and you are looking for a way to validate the input using the shell?

If you can break out the year/month/day into a slash-separated format, you can use the `date` command to test if the date stamp is valid. This runs under bash, other shells may be different

**bad**

```
$ echo -n "year :"; read year; echo -n "month :"; read month; echo -n "day :"; read day; date -d "$year/$month/$day" || echo "Not a valid date"
year :9999
month :32
day :32
date: invalid date ‘9999/32/32’
Not a valid date
```

**good**

```
$ echo -n "year :"; read year; echo -n "month :"; read month; echo -n "day :"; read day; date -d "$year/$month/$day" || echo "Not a valid date"
year :2020
month :3
day :23
Mon Mar 23 00:00:00 CDT 2020
```

Comment: I know it might sounds stupid, but if I do this, how do I take the date as a whole and use it to show the background processes?

Comment: I don't think you've included enough information about how you're filtering background processes in general to answer that.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Here is the actual task: a shell script that displays the processes launched in the background at a certain date. The date is a positional parameter. This is what I have to do, no other further explanations, so I am really confused because I asked around and the solutions seem too complicated for me, as I am at begginer level and we learned just the basics.

Comment: This sort of sounds like a homework assingment? You can format the output of the date given using the `date` command: eg: `date -d '12/23/33' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'`. From there, you could grep the timestamp on the process or format the `ps` output to something more usable (eg: `ps -ef -o  stime,pid,command`)

Comment: It is a homework assingment indeed. I'm a begginer so I didn't really know how to approach it. I received a good answer that works perfectly, but I do not understand it completely. Yours seems simpler, but I still don't know how I should write it as a script shell. Thanks for your answer tho:)